# Drag & drop: detecting what you're dropping on

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, drag-and-drop, uipopovercontroller

Assembled elders of the Cocoa-Touch, I have a question for you all about Drag & Drop on the iPad.

I am attempting to drag an item from a popover onto an underlying canvas. Employing the UIPanGestureRecognizer class I can detect a drag-start and create a UIView to drag with the finger tip. My application runs in landscape mode.

The trouble comes when dragging across the tree of UIViews underneath: how can I find out what I am dragging across currently? When given [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow, [UIView hitTest:withEvent:] **always** returns a UIDimmingView (that I didn't put there). If I pass a UIView that I've created to the hitTest call then I cannot detect a drop back onto the original popover - and therefore cannot detect a "don't drag after all" gesture.

Your clues and boos are most welcome.

M.